# Printer Driver is not been specified

Tags: delphi, driver

Estou usando a tsclib.dll para imprimir etiquetas na Bematech LB-1000. Na procedure openport() já dá o erro Printer Driver is not been specified.

A impressora é local, porta USB e estou passando o nome dela como parâmetro dessa forma:

openport('Bematech');

conforme explica o manual de instruções  da dll. Mas, mesmo seguindo as instruções, esse erro continua. Usando os próprios comandos da impressora, funciona normalmente. Acredito que o problema esteja realmente na dll.

Alguém já passou por esse problema e sabe como me ajudar?

código:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms, Dialogs,
  StdCtrls, ExtCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    GroupBox1: TGroupBox;
    Button1: TButton;
    Image1: TImage;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Label2: TLabel;
    Label3: TLabel;
    Label4: TLabel;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.DFM}
{$R GenericLIB.RES}

procedure openport(PrinterName:pchar);stdcall;far; external 'tsclib.dll';
procedure closeport; external 'tsclib.dll';
procedure sendcommand(Command:pchar);stdcall;far;external 'tsclib.dll';
procedure setup(LabelWidth, LabelHeight, Speed, Density, Sensor, Vertical,             Offset:pchar);stdcall; far; external 'tsclib.dll';
procedure downloadpcx(Filename,ImageName:pchar);stdcall;far;external     'tsclib.dll';
procedure barcode(X, Y, CodeType, Height, Readable, Rotation, Narrow, Wide,     Code :pchar); stdcall; far; external 'tsclib.dll';
procedure printerfont(X, Y, FontName, Rotation, Xmul, Ymul,     Content:pchar);stdcall;far; external 'tsclib.dll';
procedure clearbuffer; external 'tsclib.dll';
procedure printlabel(NumberOfSet, NumberOfCopoy:pchar);stdcall; far;external     'C:\Windows\System32\tsclib.dll';
procedure formfeed;external 'tsclib.dll';
procedure nobackfeed; external 'tsclib.dll';
procedure windowsfont (X, Y, FontHeight, Rotation, FontStyle, FontUnderline : integer; FaceName, TextContect:pchar);stdcall;far;external 'tsclib.dll';

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;

begin

  openport('Bematech');
        for i:=1 to 1 do
         begin
          clearbuffer;
          sendcommand('DIRECTION 1');
          windowsfont(10, 10, 30, 0, 2, 0, 'arial', 'Exemplo LB - 1000     Delphi - Bematech');
          barcode('10', '100', '128', '100', '1', '0', '2', '2', '1234567-    BEMATECH');
          printlabel('1', '1');
        end;
          closeport;


end;

end.
```

Comment: Você já checou em `Painel de Controle > Dispositivos e Impressoras` se a impressora aparece lá com esse nome que você definiu?

Comment: Você chegou a seguir esse tutorial http://partners.bematech.com.br/bemacast/Paginas/post.aspx?idPost=6112 ?

Comment: Sim @Sorack, ela aparece e está com esse nome.

Comment: Coloca o código completo do seu procedimento que executa a impressão, por favor.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27979316/2221388 veja se lhe ajuda.

Comment: @PabloVargas segui sim esse tutorial. E também já li esse post.

Comment: Você consegue enviar uma página de teste pelas configurações da impressora no Gerenciador de Dispositivos?

Comment: @Sorack editei a pergunta e coloquei o código.

Comment: @PabloVargas pelas propriedades da impressora? Se sim, imprime normalmente. Acredito que o problema está mesmo nessa procedure, porque mandando os comando diretamente na impressora, sem utilizar dll, funciona perfeitamente.

Comment: Tua impressora chama "BEM" mesmo?

Comment: Kamila, no open port você deve colocar o nome da impressora bem como aparece no Gerenciador de Dispositivos.

Comment: @Sorack alterei para Bematech. Mas mesmo informando o nome que está nos dispositivos e impressoras ou colocando o nome da porta, que ´é USB001 o erro persiste.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consegui resolver meu problema com a ajuda do Suporte da Bematech. Segue a Solução:

Primeiramente, o código de exemplo disponibilizado no site da Bematech é para Delphi 7. A minha IDE é Delphi 10. Já comecei errado rsrs. Realmente não me atentei a isso.
Segundo o analista, "O problema ocorre devido a divergência na estrutura das variáveis que tenha caracteres Alfabéticos entre a versão 7 com a posteriores do Delphi. sendo obrigatório o uso das variáveis Ansi nas chamadas das funções da DLL que tenham que se passar String ou Char."

Então peguei com o suporte a versão da aplicação em Delphi 10 e deu certo. A DLL e o driver estão corretos.

Se alguém se interessa em pegar o código fonte este é o link para fazer o download: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9ho7vuzo7y1g4rg/Novo%20Lb1000%20Exemplo%20em%20Delphi%202010.rar?dl=0

À todos que tentaram ajudar, muito obrigada!

Comment: Você poderia subir no github o código fonte https://github.com/

Comment: @PabloVargas obrigada pela dica. Vou subir e colocar o link na resposta.

Comment: Coloquei o projeto todo, penso que é melhor.